# Powerpivot DAX - I need a way to show a value for Revenue in my profit & loss statement even if there is no Revenue

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I am having an issue with a consolidated profit and loss statement using calculated fields. There is a column for GL Group, which is either Revenue or Expense. The calculated field asks "if the value of the row is Revenue then flip the sign of the number", and "if it is expense to leave it as is". And for the net income it takes the sum of both and flips the sign to give you a net profit. My issue is that if there is NO revenue then its BLANK and then expenses, which come through naturally as a positive number, remains a positive number on the net income but should rather be a negative. This is what I am looking to achieve: Revenue should be ZERO if its blank, minus expenses, the result of this will always be a negative number (remember the expenses show as positive). Looking to improve this code:

```
IF(HASONEVALUE(ActualsBudgetsOB[GL_GROUP]),IF(VALUES(ActualsBudgetsOB[GL_GROUP])="Revenue",CALCULATE(SUM(ActualsBudgetsOB[AMT_ACTUAL])
,FILTER(ActualsBudgetsOB,ActualsBudgetsOB[FISCAL_YR]=[Max Year])
,FILTER(ActualsBudgetsOB,ActualsBudgetsOB[PERIOD]<=[Max Period]))*-1,CALCULATE(SUM(ActualsBudgetsOB[AMT_ACTUAL])
,FILTER(ActualsBudgetsOB,ActualsBudgetsOB[FISCAL_YR]=[Max Year])
,FILTER(ActualsBudgetsOB,ActualsBudgetsOB[PERIOD]<=[Max Period]))),CALCULATE(SUM(ActualsBudgetsOB[AMT_ACTUAL])
,FILTER(ActualsBudgetsOB,ActualsBudgetsOB[FISCAL_YR]=[Max Year])
,FILTER(ActualsBudgetsOB,ActualsBudgetsOB[PERIOD]<=[Max Period]))*-1)
```